# not found object Prop, scalacheck

Tags: eclipse, jar, scala-ide, scalacheck

i'm following the exact same instructions of:
http://lamp.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lamp/files/teaching/progfun/ScalacheckTutorial.html

to add the scalacheck jar to the scala-ide but the IDE is giving me this: "object Prop not found" when importing

```
import org.scalacheck._
import Prop.forAll
```

scala-IDE version: 4.4.0
os version: Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
scala version: 2.11.8
java version: 1.8.0_45
scalacheck: 2.11.1-1.12.5-sources

Answer (score 0):

You need to add fully package name `import org.scalacheck.Prop`

Comment: i already did this but the problem still continue :-/ plus this is the form that have the example